# Destroy user session without Devise Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I will try to do a simple user authorization without Devise.
My session controller has new, create and destroy actions:

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(name: user_params[:name])
    @user ||= User.create(user_params)
    if @user.valid? && @user.authenticate(user_params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to tasks_path
    end
  end

  def destroy
    reset_session
  end
```

But it doesn't work. How can I destroy a user session?

Comment: Hi! Could you add some info to your question? What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'? Do you have an error?

Comment: I don't have an error. But current_user variable is not be empty or nil after calling a destroy action. In aplication controller I have this method: def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

Comment: Hi, I think your problem could be on your reset_session method, maybe it's in your helper class. Could you update your answer with its content? You should have a destroy from session hash of your user_id or something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it.  It really depends on what kind of helpers you have set up.  You'll need access to the session variable you created and also the user id, so `session.delete(@user.id)`  might end up being what you need.  Depends on how this is being sent over to the method and what data you have access to (is there a before action or something providing the @user variable or do you need to find it with something like `@user = User.find(:params)` where params is the user id.

```
def destroy
  session.delete(:user_id)
  @user = nil
end
```